# Limit as $x$ approaches infinity of $\cos(\pi x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, continuity, graphing-functions

This question is if $\cos(\pi n)$ and $\sin(\pi n)$ have a limit and how to calculate it.
Do $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\cos(\pi n)-\frac{1}{n})$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sin(\pi n)-\frac{1}{n})$ exist ?
If yes how to calculate them?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The value of sin n and cos n always lies in the range of -1 to 1.

Also, ∞ is undefined thus, sin(∞) and cos(∞) cannot have exact defined values.

However, sin n and cos n are periodic functions having a periodicity of (2π).

Thus, the value of sin and cos infinity lies between -1 to 1. There are no exact values defined for them.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the two subsequences $\cos(2k\pi)$ and $\cos((2k-2)\pi)$ where $k$ is a natural number. Do something similar for $\sin(\pi n)$. Notice that the two subsequences have distinct limits so clearly the sequence doesn't converge.